# Multiple rcarousel on one page

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm having trouble showing the left nav button on the second carousel using rcarousel (http://ryrych.github.io/rcarousel/). I've been looking at it for ages and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. The code is below and the carousel not working is the carouselDirectory one.

Any ideas?

Javascript....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {

        $("#carousel").rcarousel({
            width: 180,
            height: 130,
            visible: 5,
            step: 1


        });

        jQuery(function($) {
            $("#carousel").rcarousel({
                auto: {
                    enabled: true,
                    interval: 3000,
                    direction: "next",


                }
            });

        });


        $("#carouselDirectory").rcarousel({
            width: 180,
            height: 130,
            visible: 5,
            step: 1,

            navigation: {
                prev: "#ui-banner-carousel-prev",
                next: "#ui-banner-carousel-next"


            }

        });

    }); 
</script>
```

HTML...

```
<div id="business">
    <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF; margin-bottom: 1em;">
        <div id="carousel">
            <a href="http://www.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/employment.png" alt="Employment"/></a>
            <a href="http://www.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/property.png" alt="Property"/></a>
            <a href="http://www.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/rent.png" alt="Rent"/></a>
            <a href="http://www.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/land.png" alt="Land"/></a>
            <a href="http://www.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/business.png" alt="Business"/></a>
            <a href="http://www.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/franchise.png" alt="Franchise"/></a>
            <a href="http://www.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/health.png" alt="Health"/></a>
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="ui-carousel-next"><span>next</span></a>
        <a href="#" id="ui-carousel-prev"><span>prev</span></a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="widget/lib/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="widget/lib/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="widget/lib/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="widget/lib/jquery.ui.rcarousel.js"></script>
    <div class="business-title">
        Business Directory
    </div>
    <div id="carouselDirectory">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/small/business-directory.jpg" alt="business directory"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/small/blank.jpg" alt="image02"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/small/blank.jpg" alt="image02"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/small/blank.jpg" alt="image02"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/small/blank.jpg" alt="image02"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/small/blank.jpg" alt="image02"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/small/blank.jpg" alt="image02"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/small/blank.jpg" alt="image02"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/small/blank.jpg" alt="image02"/></a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="ui-banner-carousel-next"><span>next</span></a>
    <a href="#" id="ui-banner-carousel-prev"><span>prev</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any mention in your plugin documentation that multiple carousels can be implemented on the same page. Can you please post to JSFiddle so we can check this?

Comment: Apperently it can be done, I found this site that someone has achieved it with... https://github.com/ryrych/rcarousel/issues/13

Comment: Perfect, please post your code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can find what the problem is.

Comment: I can't get it to work on JSFiddle, never used this before. IS it possible to compare the link above with mine and see if its right?

Comment: I've put it online mate, it can be seen here... http://bit.ly/1333XZg

Comment: Thanks. The second carousel seems correctly initialized with your plugin. Please try to remove your first plugin and check if it works so we can make sure this is a problem with many carousels running at the same time.

Comment: I just noticed this, why do you use two times `$("#carousel").rcarousel` in your code? Try to remove the second one and move parameters to the first one.